# How to evaluate $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} ((n+1)\ln(n+1))^c-(n\ln(n))^c$ where $c \in (0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The original question is that I want to evaluate
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} ((n+1)\ln(n+1))^{\frac{1}{2}}-(n\ln(n))^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Now I want to find if for any $c \in (0,1)$, $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} ((n+1)\ln(n+1))^c-(n\ln(n))^c=0$$ holds.
I prefer to evaluate it by definition, Cauchy sequence, or squeeze lemma. I don't want to use L'Hospital rule. I think I only need a hint.

For the original question, I have tried to represent $$((n+1)\ln(n+1))^{\frac{1}{2}}-(n\ln(n))^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ as $$(n\ln(n))^{\frac{1}{2}}(((1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}))^{\frac{1}{2}}-1)$$
but lost insight to continue. That is a dull idea. But was it not $\frac{1}{2}$, this kind of idea would turn to be the only way I can think, again. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Hint: often the trick helps $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$.

Comment: @A.G. Ah, how can I didn't notice it at all... but if it is not $\frac{1}{2}$, this trick seems to fail...

Comment: Still possible to use the idea that $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+\ldots+y^{n-1})$, but it becomes messier.

Comment: @A.G., $c$ does not need to be integer.

Comment: One way is to use $f(n+1) - f(n) = f'(n + \theta_n)$ for some $\theta_n\in (0,1)$, since the function $x \mapsto (x\ln x)^c$ is differentiable on $(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer That seems great! But if... If I want to keep the function idea away (which is, I think, in some degree more general then concept of sequence), I want to know if there is still a way? ;)

Comment: I don't see any neat tricks for general $c\in (0,1)$. Writing the difference as $$(n\ln n)^c\bigl( (1 + R_n)^c - 1\bigr)$$ works, of course. But it's not particularly exciting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

$$ ((n+1)\log(n+1))^c- (n\log(n))^c $$
is the value of the derivative of $f(x)=\left(x\log x\right)^{c}$ at some point $x_0\in(n,n+1)$.
Since $f'(x) = c(\log x+1) \left(x\log x\right)^{c-1}$,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} ((n+1)\log(n+1))^c- (n\log(n))^c = 0 $$
for **any** $c\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Mine agrees with yours. Comforting.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
((n+1)\log(n+1))^c- (n\log(n))^c
&=(n+1)^c(\log n+\log(1+1/n))^c- (n\log(n))^c\\
&=n^c(1+1/n)^c(\log n)^c(1+\log(1+1/n)/\log n)^c- (n\log(n))^c\\
&\approx n^c(1+c/n)(\log n)^c(1+1/(n\log n))^c- (n\log(n))^c\\
&\approx n^c(1+c/n)(\log n)^c(1+c/(n\log n))- (n\log(n))^c\\
&\approx n^c(\log n)^c(1+c/n+c/(n\log n)+c/(n^2\log n))- (n\log(n))^c\\
&= n^c(\log n)^c(c/n+c/(n\log n)+c/(n^2\log n))\\
&= cn^{c-1}(\log n)^c(1+1/(\log n)+1/(n\log n))\\
&\approx cn^{c-1}(\log n)^c\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{since } 0 < c < 1\\
\end{array}
$